# What's the Difference between CDR and xDR

Tags: telecommunication

I want to know what's the difference between CDR and XDR.When I read articles i found CDR(Call Detail Record )and xDR(x Data Record),but i don't understand the difference between them.Can someone tell me what's the difference between them and thank you an advance

Comment: Have you Googled `Difference between CDR and xDR`? The first result is what looks like a decent answer.

Comment: Yes but I  just found this :https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.object.corba/po88fJULWkI

Comment: But that looks like a good answer, no? What else do you need to know?

Comment: I want to know technically the difference between them

Comment: The relation between them

Comment: I'm not sure whether these things are comparable at all, and whether the CDR in the linked answer refers to telecommunication at all. What is your real-world problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: because they dont know answer and just write 'did you search on google ' ahahah

Answer (score 4):

CDR or Call Detail Record is the *voice* channel. XDR is the *data* channel. For example, one difference is that CDRs encode 2 phone numbers and two antennas (in and out) for a call, while XDRs only contain one antenna (the one you're connected to and downloading information)... no "out" antenna or "out" phone number is nedded. Another difference is perhaps that you're not measured in how many minutes you burn, but how many KBs you down/upload. There are more details, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:
CDR is for old school voice calls (ISUP protocol for example). And is used on active switching equipment.

XDR is for any generic signaling (SMS, Mobility Management, Data session etc. incl. calls)

And for data there is UDR (User Data Record) which represents info about "internet" usage.

Answer (score 1):

xDR contains all thing that mentioned (CDRS, EDR, ...).
they are relating to telecommunication industry

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).